# Is there a clue for the hidden switch in the village?

Tags: monster-boy

In Monster Boy and the cursed Kingdom, in the main village, there is this puzzle with hidden switches scattered all around the place.

Is there a clue somewhere which shows you the location of these switches ?

Or do you have to attack everywhere blindly hoping to stumble on them ?